# Is { abcFunc(arg1, arg2){ /*FuncBody*/ } } new Object method syntax?

Tags: javascript, object

When i was reading MDN docs i got the following Objects syntax's,

```
var o = {
  a: 7,
  get b() { 
    return this.a + 1;
  },
  set c(x) {
    this.a = x / 2;
  }
};

// ...
```

[From Here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) At first i thought, It was only for `get` & `set`. But then i saw this,

```
// ...

const handler = {
  getPrototypeOf(target) {
    return monsterPrototype;
  }
};

// ...
```

[From Here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/getPrototypeOf) And When i tested with custom function it worked. here,

```
let obj = {
  _sum: 0,
  sum(a, b) {
    return this._sum += (a + b);
  }
}

console.log(obj.sum(2, 3));    // int 5
console.log(obj.sum(7, 3));    // int 15
console.log(obj.sum(25, 75));  // int 115
```

It also works like this with expression !!

```
let obj = {
  _sum: 0,
  ['su' + 'm'](a, b) {
    return this._sum += (a + b);
  }
}

console.log(obj.sum(2, 3));    // int 5
console.log(obj.sum(7, 3));    // int 15
console.log(obj.sum(25, 75));  // int 115
```

> I searched MDN, googled for new Objects Method Syntax, but still couldn't find this kind of syntax. So, I just want to if its a standard syntax which i can use or A experimental technology. I am using *Chome* v79.

Comment: **TL;DR you should be using babeljs.  Just use babeljs.**  fyi if you are worried about "experimental"  or poor support, you should be using BabelJS.  They even have presets to target minimum browser support: [BabelJS Usage Guide: Configuration](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage#configuration)

Answer (score 2):

You're using two types of syntaxes introduced in ES6. The first is known as "shorthand method names" and the other is known as [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). So they're not considered experimental technology and have been part of the standard since 2015. You can find the syntax for shorthand method names in section [14.3](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-PropertyName) of the spec as well as computed property names in section [12.2.6](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ComputedPropertyName).

Shorthand method names allow you to omit the `function` keyword so that the name of the method is used as the property name:

> In ECMAScript 2015, a shorthand notation is available, so that the
> keyword "function" is no longer necessary.

Your last code block combines both shorthand method names and computed property names to create the method name `sum` at runtime. Computed property names allow you to add properties to object literals as expressions, this means that it doesn't just have to be used for object methods, but can be used for standard object literal properties:

```js
const obj = {
  ["k" + "ey"]: 1
}
console.log(obj.key); // 1
```

You can use shorthand method names and computed property names in most modern browsers, however, Internet Explorer currently [doesn't support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility) these two syntaxes.

You can read more about method definitions in objects [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Method_definitions)

Comment: Is "shorthand method names" the blessed keyword name or term, or a generally accepted (informal) name, or just a popular one? I find the term a little bit too misleading, even if I can't think of a nicer name (like arrow function syntax).  To say it is a "shorthand" is okay, but to use "shorthand method names" as a way to refer to the syntax as a whole, I think, is glossing over explicit (and important) goals and use cases of the syntax (eg: class syntax features and getters/setters).

Comment: @user120242 I'm going off of the name used on MDN. I believe that the name is derived from short-hand property names for object literals, as they somewhat behave in a similar way, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

[Method Definitions specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-method-definitions)

From [BabelJS Learn ES2015: Enhanced Object Literals](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/learn/#enhanced-object-literals):

> defining methods and making super calls [...] bring object literals and class declarations closer together, and let object-based design benefit from some of the same conveniences.

Note that the object literal syntax enhancements (which categorically encompasses method definitions) had the explicit goal for not only bringing in class syntax, but the conveniences of class syntax to classical Javascript syntax.

There are two main differences from functions as object properties, where methods are not just a simple shorthand for functions as object properties.

1. Support for `super` syntax, which allows accessing properties on the inherited prototype chain
2. Like arrow functions, they cannot be used as constructors.  `new object.method` will fail if method is declared using method definition syntax
   Note: methods are different from (and in a way opposite to) arrow functions and have context (this binding), and they work with [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Note: `super` is a syntax level feature, and there is only a difference when super is detected. see [14.3.4 HasDirectSuper](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-method-definitions-static-semantics-hasdirectsuper)

Demo of the usage of `super` and TypeError thrown when trying to use method property as a constructor.

```js
x = {
  method() {
    return super.toString()
  },
  toString() {
    return 'fake'
  },
  prop: function(){}  
}

console.log(`x.method()->super.toString() : ${x.method()}`)
console.log(`x.toString(): ${x.toString()}`)
console.log(`new x.prop: `, new x.prop)
try{
console.log(`new x.method: `,new x.method)
} catch(e) {console.log(`new x.method error: ${e.toString()}`)}
```

`super` failing when used in a function as an object property demoed separately, since it is a syntax level error and would block parsing:

```js
obj = { notmethod: function() { return super.toString() } }
```